# Finding FB friends and GMail contacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, gmail

I'm a RoR newbie, building an app that allows users to register/link their FB and/or GMail accounts.

For example, User1 registers/links using their FB and Gmail accounts.  Once registered, User1 recommends Sushi as their favorite meal.

User2 registers with their FB account, and happens to also be a friend (via FB) of User1.  User2 then wants to see what the favorite meals are of people that are registered within the application, and only those they are connected to within FB.

User3 registers with their Gmail account, and happens to be in the contact list of User1.  User3 then wants to see what the favorite meals are of people that are registered within the application, and only those they are connected to within Gmail contacts.

In reading the FB/Google API docs, I see that I can query for user's friends and/or contacts, but from a programmatic/performance perspective I'm having trouble wrapping my head around how to accomplish this, especially as the number of users grows.  I don't want to store each and every relationship in my DB, so I'm looking for any advice/examples on how to accomplish this.

Thanks for your time and assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that shouldn´t be a problem.

Once your users are registered with your App. You can use for example Facebook FQL API to check which of the FB users friends are registered with your App.

Spotify doesn´t update your friendslist often. You can cache his/her friendslist once a while if you have performance problems inside a NOSQL database since you are already getting JSON from Facebook API.